# Remove Punctuation Characters (keep alphanumeric and unicode) Java

Tags: regex, string, unicode

Trying to remove all punctuation characters but keep all alphanumeric and other similar unicode type characters needed for language (i.e. not math symbols).  For example:

```
test1string                =>     test1string
test2-string               =>     test2string
test.3!string              =>     test3string
тестовоезадание!строка.    =>     тестовоезаданиестрока
String               =>     String
```

Can come up with more examples to clarify questions as needed.  Currently using `[\\w\\p{l}]+` to allow desired values but its converting many characters to `?`.

Comment: What is the regex library? What kind of letters/digits do you want to keep?

Comment: This is being done in Java. I tagged it with regex and that's what is currently being used to try and solve this, but it doesn't have to be (and that may be preferred for performance reasons)

Comment: Try `text.replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]+|[\\p{L}&&[^\\x00-\\x{FFFF}]]+", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
text.replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]+|[\\p{L}&&[^\\x00-\\x{FFFF}]]+", "")
```

**Details**

- `[\p{P}\p{S}]+` - 1 or more punctuation and symbols
- `|` - or
- `[\p{L}&&[^\x00-\x{FFFF}]]+` - 1 or more letters other than those defined in BMP plane.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ARXmsq):

```
String text = "test1string\ntest2-string\ntest.3!string\nтестовоезадание!строка.\nString";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]+|[\\p{L}&&[^\\x00-\\x{FFFF}]]+", ""));
```

Output:

```
test1string
test2string
test3string
тестовоезаданиестрока
String
```